# Issue with boxcutter applying weird size offset to cutters

Tags: add-on

As you can see below, whenever I start to draw a new cutter the cutter starts with some sort of negative offset making it very annoying to draw precise cutters. When I lock the shape and create the cut in the extrude phase the cut actually has the correct size (it then appears smaller - see screenshot below GIF). So the functionality seems untouched by this issue just the cutter shape itself visually has the wrong size.

I have re-installed both blender and boxcutter.
This suddenly happens (triggered by some action I don't know, I guess) during the modelling process. When I create a new file the issue is gone. Closing and re-loading my project file won't fix it either.

There is no setting in boxcutter that could cause this either.

[image: cutter size issue happens during drawing phase]

[image: cutter after locking shape]

Comment: Boxcutter is a commercial third-party addon so we can't really help with that, but have you applied the scale (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) to your original object?

Comment: @JohnEason I know, but I have searched the internet for days now and have not found anyone with the same issue. Yes I have applied the scale.

Comment: Have you checked with the addon developers?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I believe it occurs when using smaller objects, as in my case, where I used 2 inches by 2 inches for precise electrical item modeling.